# Why do disabled controls still perform validation

Tags: c#, validation, controls

Can someone help with this?
I am using c#

Why do DISABLED controls raise the validation event?!

The user selects one of two options.
Each option will enable a GroupBox and disable the second one and vice versa.
The problem is that i need validation from the controls from the two GroupBox controls and when i disable the GroupBox the controls inside it STILL perform validation. This causes the problem. When i click the button it can not process the input because validation fails on DISABLED controls.

why do this happen?
It is not supposed that disabled controls do not raise certain events like validation?

Answer (score 0):

You mean in ASP.NET ?????
If Yes, you have to make `CausesValidation`  flag to `false`

```
<asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server"
  Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="False">
</asp:Button>
```

Same can be done through Codebehind by disabling the `Validator`

Comment: I am using C# - Windows Forms application.

Comment: i think windows form also has CausesValidation flag, try use to false